# Weighted products based on purchase dates

Tags: analysis, arithmetic

I am working on a market basket analysis. I have a data set with a number of purchases the last year. So, I have baskets of products along with the purchased date.
I need to calculate a weight for each product based on the dates that it was bought. The most recently a product was being bought, the larger weight it will have.

```
For example:
**Basket**       **Days before today**
{A,B,C,D}               350
{A,B,E,F}               320
{A,B,G,H,I}             300
{E,F,B,K}               25
{A,E,J,K}               10
{E,F}                   5
```

In the above example, products A and B should have a lower weight than the products E and F. As products E and F were frequently bought recently.
What would be a mathematical approach to calculate those weights.

Comment: Do you have any other requirements for the weights? The weight, as you describe it, should be a function of "days before today", and it should be a decreasing function. There are infinitely many ways to construct a decreasing function, you could for example use $f(x) = 1/ x$ , where $x$ is the number of days ...

Comment: ... or if you want to fine tune it, you can use $f(x)= \frac{1}{x^p}$ for some constant $p$. Then you can choose different values for $p$ and see if it matches what you want.

Comment: @MattiP. So, for product A it should be w = 1/(350+320+300+10) ? In that way product F will get a larger weight than E.  Products with high frequency will get low weights. But this is not correct.